# Invalid Code Signing Entitlements for frameworks - ERROR ITMS-90046

Tags: ios

Ever since I enabled `use frameworks!` in my Podfile, I received the following error for all of the pod frameworks. This occurs when I try to submit the app to the app store for TestFlight distribution.

```
ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. 
Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. 
Specifically, value 'TEAM_ID.com.app.app' for key 'application-identifier' in 'Payload/App.app/Frameworks/SomeLib.framework/SomeLib' is not supported. 
This value should be a string starting with your TEAMID, followed by a dot '.', followed by the bundle identifier."
```

I added the following post_install settings in my Podfile since Pods should not be code signed.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?